# Is Azure limiting outgoing connections

Tags: azure

I'm running a VM in Azure on which I have a service that makes a lot of outgoing http client calls. After a while (approx 10 minutes) when the service has made around 5000-10000 calls it suddenly starts to get Connection Refused as reponse to the requests.

When running the same service locally (tried in many environments and computers) it runs without any error. We are using the HttpClient class for the request.
The requests are done in 3 tasks running concurrently.

Is there some limits on the amount of outgoing connections in Azure that I should be aware of?

Comment: Are you sure you're not causing any thread starvation by not disposing HttpClient properly? What is the VM Size you use? I suspect Small (which has 1 Core and 1.75GB Ram) when compare to your local PC where you have a least 4 Cores? Thx.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be our code. When we are running the service and get the errors on the VM I opened chrome on the VM and tried the REST call from there and got the same error... So it seems to be a machine/infrastructure problem, not code per se.

Comment: If it's a port/thread starvation it doesn't matter how you access the Http stack, you're still going to have the same behavior. Our limits for concurrent TCP connections is 500K. The only other thing I can imagine is that you trigger some DDoS alert and you get limited by that. The things to check are: 1) Do you have enough BW at that moment? 2) Do you have enough threads available 3) Try a different role size and see if it behaves the same. Then it confirms my DDoS theory. If not, then it's something else.

Comment: Ok. Thanks will check it. Tried it on a VM on our local network accessing the remote host (which isn't ours) with the exact same configuration and it works... But the same VM in Azure gets the errors... So that suggests it would't be a thread problem, right?

Comment: Was the local machine the same specs as the one you use on Azure? If yes, then it's not a thread issue. If not, this might still be a valid reason. Might not be *the* reason, but still a thing to look into.

Comment: Pretty much.The local VM was 1 Gb RAM and one core. The Azure vm has 2 Cores and 7 GB (we have tried lower configs as well)

Comment: What does your Monitor report status inside Azure management portal for your VM state?

Comment: Have you tried changing amount of http connections for your VM via HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\MaxConnections (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/820129)?

Comment: Do you have all `HttpClient` instances proper disposed after they are no longer used?

Comment: We are investigating a similar scenario, we have a azure website making https calls to a external API. At one time it stopped working because connection failed. Trying it with curl in the console (in kudu) it gives "Failed connect". Any other call to other sites http and https work. Looks like something is dropping connection to that particular ip. Is this some automatic security guard to avoid outgoing DDOS? Seems strage but couldn't think of anything different. Did you come up with a explanation/solution? Thanks.

Comment: not sure how everyone is trying to solve the problem without even asking for what kind of error messages are you getting? The error messages may be able to tell you if the connection is being throttled or remote server is denying your requests because you are making lot of calls.

Comment: Not only VM it has outbound connnection limit on app services as well . why are these restrictions we have what if we work on api based apps ? @RichardHoultz did you find any solutions for this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a maximum connection limit per azure subscription.

You should reuse the connections instead of opening new ones.

Read more about it here: http://www.freekpaans.nl/2015/08/starving-outgoing-connections-on-windows-azure-web-sites/

Answer (score 3):

We have hit similar issues in the past, and looks like the VMs have an outbound connection limit of 1024 to an external IP. Internal Azure IPs, when they are in the same data center won't have this limitation since internal routing tables are able to handle those connections.

There is a lot of relevant information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections#snatexhaust

Summarizing key points:

1. Try assigning a public IP to your VM if it doesn't have one. This is only viable if you are running a handful of VMs.
2. Try adding multiple IPs to your VNET/Load balancer if you are running behind one. Each external IP will multiply your connection limit.
3. Try optimizing your connection usage, i.e. keep connections alive for longer for efficient pipe-lining.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux VM, execute the below command to check the limit on open files/sockets

```
Ulimit - d cmd will give the value. The default is 1024
```

You can permanently change this value by appending the following in your limits.conf file

```
*soft nofile 65536
*hard nofile 65536
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware of Azure DNS throttling.

> DNS query traffic is throttled for each VM. Throttling shouldn't impact most applications. If request throttling is observed, ensure that client-side caching is enabled. For more information, see DNS client configuration.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but may be helpful for others. 
Yes Azure has outbound connection limits as per subscriptions. 
**Solution:** 
Do not use multiple `http client` instances use single instance per application.

Reference link for connection limits is [Here](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/03/01/Deep-Dive-into-TCP-Connections-in-App-Service-Diagnostics.html) 

**Example:** 
How to use single instance example C# from [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here is the [Azure page for service limits](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/).  It does not specify a call per time frame but does set max network connections for TCP as 500K and below that table there are settings for "Web Apps (Websites) Limits" that you may be reaching.

Answer (score -2):

There is a limit of 500K TCP connections on a VM or web role (behind the scenes a web role sits on a VM as well). You can refer to the link below for  [Azure limits](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/#networking-limits)

Looks like your application is heavy on making outbound requests. In such a scenario, you might want to decouple this piece and use 'Azure functions' [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) which gives you a serverless architecture capability.

Answer (score -3):

Without knowing Azure at all, I wonder if the problem is that your VM has a limit on the number of TCP sockets - all of those (closed) TCP connections in FIN-WAIT state might have exhausted some limit set for Azure that isn't set in other circumstances.  This is pure speculation.