# Azure App Service - Outbound IPs Changed?

Tags: mysql, azure

I have a site running on an Azure App Service. It connects to a MySQL DB on Google CloudSQL.
All of a sudden I am getting an error when I hit a page on my site. The error is:

`Configuration Error - Reading from the stream has failed.`

I know this is related to MySQL and an attempt to read from the DB.
The DB itself is fine - minimal connections, no stress.
The site runs fine from my local VS connecting to said database.

This makes me think I have hit some kind of 'outbound' connection limit on Azure. Can anyone confirm?

The Azure site is up and running but as soon as it tries to connect to the DB it falls over.

Thanks for any help you can give!

## Update - IP Changed??

It appears that the App Service outbound IP addresses changed at some point yesterday so our external MySQL DB started blocking the connection attempts. Has anyone experienced this? Every single outbound IP changed. Nothing has been changed on the setup of the app (no scaling etc)

Comment: App Service limits listed here https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#numerical-sandbox-limits also can be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269364/is-azure-limiting-outgoing-connections

Comment: @Lanorkin thanks - it appears that the App Service outbound IPs all changed?!

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450619/how-to-determine-azure-website-outgoing-ip-address

Comment: Also here recent MS reply https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/03/02/how-to-find-you-outgoing-azure-app-service-ip-address/ "Are these outbound IPs guaranteed to remain the same as long as the azure web site isn’t deleted?"-"there is no guarantee, but they will not change from 1 day to the next, nor is there any plan or real need to change them. I have read that if this ever happens those impacted will get enough warning to make any changes to their systems to prevent any problems. They are never expected to change and you should feel comfortable that they will remain static"

Comment: @Lanorkin thanks. we had no warning here! Very strange. It's never happened to us on our other Azure deployments.